# make is automatically attempting to link even when I pass -c in my makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I'm new to makefiles, so I apologize in advance if this is a silly question. Also I removed most variables from my makefile because they weren't working properly (gnu make tells me that $(myvar) should be completely replaces by the value of myvar, however the output of make was showing me that this was not happening), so I apologize for the ugliness and the more than 80 character lines.

```
acolibobj = acoLibInit acoGlobalDefs
acolibinterface: $(acolibobj).o
acoLibInit.o:
    gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall -I/usr/include/dc1394 -o acoLibinit.o acoCommands/acoLibInterface/acoLibInit.c
acoGlobalDefs.o:
    gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall -I/usr/include/dc1394 -o acoGlobalDefs.o acoCommands/acoLibInterface/acoGlobalDefs.c
```

When I run this makefile I get:

```
gcc -fPIC -g -c -Wall -I/usr/include/dc1394 -o acoLibinit.o acoCommands/acoLibInterface/acoLibInit.c
cc   acoLibInit.o   -o acoLibInit
gcc: acoLibInit.o: No such file or directory
gcc: no input files
make: *** [acoLibInit] Error 1
```

So far as I can tell, what's happening is that make is trying to compile AND link, even though I explicitly added the -c flag. When I run "gcc -fPIC -g -c..." myself (from bash), I do not get any problems at all. Why does make go on to try "cc acoLibInit.o -o acolibInit"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make` is trying to build `acoLibInit`. It probably has built-in rule that specifies `"whatever" can be produced by linking "whatever.o"`, which is why you get that `cc` line.

This line:

```
acolibinterface: $(acolibobj).o
```

expands to:

```
acolibinterface: acoLibInit acoGlobalDefs.o
```

(note the absence of `.o` on the first dependency). This is why it's trying to link `acoLibInit`.

Try this:

```
acolibinterface: $(addsuffix .o,$(acolibobj))
```

if you want only the `.o` files as dependencies for that target.

Answer (score 2):

`$(acolibobj).o` expands to `acoLibInit acoGlobalDefs.o`.  Thus, you're really saying:

```
acolibinterface: acoLibInit acoGlobalDefs.o
```

Simply define `acolibobj = acoLibInit.o acoGlobalDefs.o` and use `acolibinterface: $(acolibobj)`.